# Bootstrap 4 counter - max-duration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, counter, duration

How to set max duration? It would be good to set the speed for each meter separately. It is not required. Anyone can help me solve my problem?
my code:

```
<section id="counter" class="counter py-3">
<div class="stat w-100 row">
<div class="milestone-counter">
  <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
  <span class="stat-count">12500</span>
  <div class="milestone-details">zadowolonych klientów</div>
</div>
<div class="milestone-counter">
  <span class="fas fa-bed"></span>
  <span class="stat-count">6000</span>
  <div class="milestone-details">przewiezionych łóżek</div>
</div>
<div class="milestone-counter"> 
  <span class="far fa-clock"></span>
  <span class="stat-count" data-delay="1">3000</span>
  <div class="milestone-details">przeprowadzek rocznie</div>
</div>
<div class="milestone-counter">
  <span class="fa fa-car"></span>
  <span class="stat-count">7</span>
  <div class="milestone-details">samochodów na mieście</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

my js (The system on which it works is wordpress.):

```
(function($) {
function isScrolledIntoView($elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
function count($this) {
    var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
    if (isScrolledIntoView($this) && !$this.data("isCounting") && current < $this.data('count')) {
        $this.html(++current);
        $this.data("isCounting", true);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.data("isCounting", false);
            count($this);
        }, 5);
    }
}
$(".stat-count").each(function () {
    $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
    $(this).html('0');
    $(this).data("isCounting", false);
});
function startCount() {
    $(".stat-count").each(function () {
        count($(this));
    });
};
$(window).scroll(function () {
    startCount();
});
startCount();
})(jQuery);
```

Changing the number 5 does not affect the countdown speed.